# Conditional column creation based on similar repetitive occurrence

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data set like

```
year <- c(2001:2015) 
id <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 5 )
status <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 2,1,0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 )
dt<- data.frame(year, id, status)
```

Hare id a, b, c, is repeated 5 times for 5 different year. Now I want to creat a new column named "fact" such that if any of the id for all the years has same status then its value is 1 otherwise 0. In that case there will be 1 for id a in the respective rows. The data set will look like

```
year <- c(2001:2015)
id <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 5 )
status <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 2,1,0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 )
fact <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
dt<- data.frame(year, id, status, fact)
```

Note: In my real data set there are 2.8 millions observations and each id is not repeated for all years.

I was trying to solve this using case_when but couldn't come up something fruitful.
I will really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(dt)[, fact := +(uniqueN(status) == 1), id]
```

gives

```
> dt
    year id status fact
 1: 2001  a      0    1
 2: 2002  b      1    0
 3: 2003  c      1    0
 4: 2004  a      0    1
 5: 2005  b      2    0
 6: 2006  c      1    0
 7: 2007  a      0    1
 8: 2008  b      1    0
 9: 2009  c      3    0
10: 2010  a      0    1
11: 2011  b      2    0
12: 2012  c      0    0
13: 2013  a      0    1
14: 2014  b      0    0
15: 2015  c      1    0
```

Comment: You could also use  `setDT(dt)[, fact := +(uniqueN(status) == 1), id]` as `uniqueN` in data.table is `length(unique`

Comment: @akrun Super! I learnt a new thing from you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the `var`iance is zero in the status groups using `ave`. The `+` converts the booleans to integer.

```
transform(dt, fact=+(ave(status, id, FUN=var) == 0))
#    year id status fact
# 1  2001  a      0    1
# 2  2002  b      1    0
# 3  2003  c      1    0
# 4  2004  a      0    1
# 5  2005  b      2    0
# 6  2006  c      1    0
# 7  2007  a      0    1
# 8  2008  b      1    0
# 9  2009  c      3    0
# 10 2010  a      0    1
# 11 2011  b      2    0
# 12 2012  c      0    0
# 13 2013  a      0    1
# 14 2014  b      0    0
# 15 2015  c      1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(fact = case_when(n_distinct(status) == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
    year id    status  fact
   <int> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2001 a          0     1
 2  2002 b          1     0
 3  2003 c          1     0
 4  2004 a          0     1
 5  2005 b          2     0
 6  2006 c          1     0
 7  2007 a          0     1
 8  2008 b          1     0
 9  2009 c          3     0
10  2010 a          0     1
11  2011 b          2     0
12  2012 c          0     0
13  2013 a          0     1
14  2014 b          0     0
15  2015 c          1     0
```

Comment: Thank your for your help. It is supposed to work but I don't know why this is not working in my pc. I even copied the code for this small data set and it gives all 0 when I run the code. I am trying to figure out is there anything wrong with my r or am I missing some thing else.